# Embedding Racket static libs in macOS desktop application (Xcode project)

Tags: swift, macos, scheme, racket

There was an [article](https://defn.io/2020/01/05/racket-on-ios/) on the internet about embedding manually built Racket libs into an iOS application. Disregarding the fact that such a possibility is more fun than useful, I've followed instructions and (ta-dah) been able to create a working example (to my surprise!).

Anyway, I was quite more eager to repeat a trick with the macOS Xcode project. There is Racket.framework included in Racket distribution and it works well with gcc (and `-framework` option) but from Xcode's perspective of view this framework doesn't have valid structure and xcodetools are not able to link to it or moreover codesign.

So I've decided to follow iOS instructions from the article but for macOS. I've built macOS Racket libraries (`librktio`, `libracket` and `libmzgc`) using `./configure` without specifying host and

- just `make`
- `make cgc && make install-cgc`

(NB: in the end result was same for both).

I've created interop C source:

```
#include "scheme.h"
#include "interop.h"
#include "racketmac.c" // <- this is my rkt module made with raco ctool

static int init(Scheme_Env *e, int argc, char *argv[]) {
    declare_modules(e);

    return 0;
}

int init_racket() {
    return scheme_main_setup(1, init, 0, NULL);
}
```

and header:

```
#ifndef Interop_h
#define Interop_h

int init_racket(void);

#endif /* Interop_h */
```

, then added "interop.h" to bridging header and C function call from Swift like:

```
import Cocoa

final public class RacketInteractor: NSObject {

    public override init() {
        super.init()

        init_racket()
    }    
}

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var interactor: RacketInteractor!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        interactor = RacketInteractor()
    }

// ...

}
```

Project, macOS Cocoa application, is build-able and runnable. But call of `init_racket` every single time results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Studying stack trace has given me understanding that scheme interpreter is trying to emit "out of memory" error (look for frame #5):

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10ad2153d)
    frame #0: 0x000000010ad2153d
  * frame #1: 0x0000000100102814 RacketMapApp`scheme_native_stack_trace at jitstack.c:215:7 [opt]
    frame #2: 0x0000000100058f7b RacketMapApp`continuation_marks(p=0x000000010a3b1250, _cont=0x0000000000000000, econt=0x0000000000000000, mc=<unavailable>, prompt_tag=0x000000010a4001d0, who="continuation-marks", just_chain=0) at fun.c:7906:10 [opt]
    frame #3: 0x000000010002d565 RacketMapApp`do_raise(arg=0x000000010ac49028, need_debug=1, eb=180654120) at error.c:4606:13 [opt]
    frame #4: 0x0000000100028f8a RacketMapApp`scheme_raise_exn(id=17) at error.c:4402:3 [opt]
    frame #5: 0x000000010002c4f7 RacketMapApp`scheme_raise_out_of_memory(where=<unavailable>, msg=<unavailable>) at error.c:2541:3 [opt]
    frame #6: 0x00000001001a02af RacketMapApp`scheme_malloc_code [inlined] malloc_page(size=<unavailable>) at salloc.c:1047:5 [opt]
    frame #7: 0x00000001001a0271 RacketMapApp`scheme_malloc_code(size=35320) at salloc.c:1156 [opt]
    frame #8: 0x00000001001035ef RacketMapApp`scheme_generate_one(old_jitter=0x0000000000000000, generate=(RacketMapApp`scheme_do_generate_common at jitcommon.c:3576), data=0x0000000000000000, gcable=0, save_ptr=0x0000000000000000, ndata=0x0000000000000000) at jitstate.c:256:18 [opt]
    frame #9: 0x000000010008f593 RacketMapApp`create_native_lambda(lam=0x000000010ac5b348, clear_code_after_jit=1, case_lam=0x0000000000000000) at jit.c:4127:5 [opt]
    frame #10: 0x0000000100101f4b RacketMapApp`scheme_jit_closure(code=0x000000010ac5b308, context=0x0000000000000000) at jitprep.c:558:13 [opt]
    frame #11: 0x0000000100101abe RacketMapApp`jit_expr(expr=0x000000010a2e3c68) at jitprep.c:0 [opt]
    frame #12: 0x0000000100101cd9 RacketMapApp`jit_expr [inlined] define_values_jit(data=<unavailable>) at jitprep.c:301:12 [opt]
    frame #13: 0x0000000100101c82 RacketMapApp`jit_expr(expr=0x000000010ac48fe8) at jitprep.c:651 [opt]
    frame #14: 0x00000001001020ce RacketMapApp`scheme_jit_linklet(linklet=0x000000010a4bfb88, step=<unavailable>) at jitprep.c:704:9 [opt]
    frame #15: 0x00000001001088f4 RacketMapApp`instantiate_linklet_k at linklet.c:0 [opt]
    frame #16: 0x000000010004ffd9 RacketMapApp`scheme_top_level_do_worker(k=(RacketMapApp`instantiate_linklet_k at linklet.c:1325), eb=<unavailable>, new_thread=0) at fun.c:1314:11 [opt]
    frame #17: 0x000000010002450f RacketMapApp`scheme_basic_env [inlined] place_instance_init(stack_base=<unavailable>, initial_main_os_thread=1) at env.c:501:3 [opt]
    frame #18: 0x000000010002436b RacketMapApp`scheme_basic_env at env.c:214 [opt]
    frame #19: 0x000000010019f7f8 RacketMapApp`scheme_main_setup [inlined] call_with_basic(data=<unavailable>) at salloc.c:178:16 [opt]
    frame #20: 0x000000010019f7f3 RacketMapApp`scheme_main_setup [inlined] do_main_stack_setup(no_auto_statics=<unavailable>, data=<unavailable>) at salloc.c:203 [opt]
    frame #21: 0x000000010019f7c3 RacketMapApp`scheme_main_setup [inlined] scheme_main_stack_setup(no_auto_statics=<unavailable>, data=<unavailable>) at salloc.c:337 [opt]
    frame #22: 0x000000010019f758 RacketMapApp`scheme_main_setup(no_auto_statics=<unavailable>, _main=(RacketMapApp`init at interop.c:14), argc=0, argv=0x0000000000000000) at salloc.c:187 [opt]
    frame #23: 0x00000001000017fb RacketMapApp`@objc RacketInteractor.init() [inlined] RacketMapApp.RacketInteractor.init() -> RacketMapApp.RacketInteractor at RacketInteractor.swift:19:9 [opt]
    frame #24: 0x00000001000017bc RacketMapApp`@objc RacketInteractor.init() at <compiler-generated>:15 [opt]
    frame #25: 0x00000001000024ed RacketMapApp`@objc AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:) [inlined] RacketMapApp.RacketInteractor.__allocating_init() -> RacketMapApp.RacketInteractor at <compiler-generated>:0 [opt]
    frame #26: 0x00000001000024e2 RacketMapApp`@objc AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:) [inlined] RacketMapApp.AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching(self=0x0000600000004320) -> () at AppDelegate.swift:17 [opt]
    frame #27: 0x00000001000024e2 RacketMapApp`@objc AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:) at <compiler-generated>:16 [opt]
    frame #28: 0x00007fff3443135f CoreFoundation`__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    frame #29: 0x00007fff344312f3 CoreFoundation`___CFXRegistrationPost1_block_invoke + 63
    frame #30: 0x00007fff34431268 CoreFoundation`_CFXRegistrationPost1 + 372
    frame #31: 0x00007fff34430ebe CoreFoundation`___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 97
    frame #32: 0x00007fff344007e2 CoreFoundation`-[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1575
    frame #33: 0x00007fff343ffc82 CoreFoundation`_CFXNotificationPost + 1351
    frame #34: 0x00007fff36a85a02 Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 59
    frame #35: 0x00007fff3160b2ff AppKit`-[NSApplication _postDidFinishNotification] + 312
    frame #36: 0x00007fff3160b042 AppKit`-[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification] + 208
    frame #37: 0x00007fff31608103 AppKit`-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 549
    frame #38: 0x00007fff31607d49 AppKit`-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 688
    frame #39: 0x00007fff36ab1226 Foundation`-[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 308
    frame #40: 0x00007fff36ab1090 Foundation`_NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 98
    frame #41: 0x00007fff357b5092 AE`___lldb_unnamed_symbol77$$AE + 2172
    frame #42: 0x00007fff357b47b9 AE`___lldb_unnamed_symbol76$$AE + 41
    frame #43: 0x00007fff357aca27 AE`aeProcessAppleEvent + 449
    frame #44: 0x00007fff32fa22b8 HIToolbox`AEProcessAppleEvent + 54
    frame #45: 0x00007fff3160215c AppKit`_DPSNextEvent + 1670
    frame #46: 0x00007fff31600690 AppKit`-[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1352
    frame #47: 0x00007fff315f23ae AppKit`-[NSApplication run] + 658
    frame #48: 0x00007fff315c4775 AppKit`NSApplicationMain + 777
    frame #49: 0x0000000100001a29 RacketMapApp`main at AppDelegate.swift:12:7 [opt]
    frame #50: 0x00007fff6ba967fd libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #51: 0x00007fff6ba967fd libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

I tried to create static lib with Interop sources and add it to the Xcode project with the same result.
At the same moment, created `librktio`, `libracket` and `libmzgc` are totally OK to be used with gcc cli. So I'm confused because I even don't know how to debug such error properly. Maybe I need to tweak some Xcode build options? Why iOS-ready libraries are working fine while macOS-ready ones aren't? Is there an easier way to embed Racket into the Xcode macOS project (through generating it via CMake, for example)?

**EDIT:** When building racket3m version, crash message is more clear, for example:

> "WARNING: couldn't protect 16384 bytes of page 0x10a350000(os/kern) protection failure"

It's like syscalls for memory allocations just don't give enough resources, and this is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "WARNING: couldn't protect 16384 bytes of page 0x10a350000(os/kern) protection failure"

Occurs when your app is missing the "Allow Unsigned Executable Memory" entitlement. Make sure your app has that and the "Allow JIT" entitlement.

But once you get past that, you'll run into Racket 3m's GC write barrier, which I briefly touch upon in the article. For that to work in debug mode, you'll have to register a signal handler in lldb to pass the expected `SIGSEGV` when it occurs. Unfortunately, there's an [LLDB bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22868) and this doesn't work on arm, but it may work on x86-64.

Comment: At least it works like a charm with cgc version. Thanks a lot! It was very useful to learn about macOS apps entitlements that I knew too little about.

Comment: In the FWIW department, we've been able to get the `s7` flavour of Scheme running on iOS and macOS successfully as an SPM (Swift Package Module). The goal is to ship it together with SQLite as an iOS & Android shared app engine. See https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/snd/snd/s7.html.